# When focus lost, type is gone in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

*I want to type something in gridview row. However when focus lost, type is gone. How can i solve this issue ?*

forexample i want to write under "Atama Yap" column:

[image]

Comment: What really happens? You click in a cell and starty typing?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič yes i click there and typing, when focus lost type is gone that is my problem

Comment: What do you mean with "focus lost"? To you click somewhere else?

Comment: This typically happens if you have not set the column's FieldName property to a property in the GridControl's data source. Can you confirm that this is set? Note that it is case sensitive.

Comment: @Brendon yes i set fieldname as "AtamaYap" in run designer  however it still doesnt work. did i do what u mean ?

Comment: What is the data source for your GridControl? For instance, if it is a DataTable, does it contain a DataColumn named "AtamaYap"? Or if it was a List<T>, is there a public property called "AtamaYap" in the T class?

Comment: thank you @Brendon i forget to add column to datatable :) thank you